# Variable 'GetTransNo' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime"

Tags: vb.net

I have Function Called GetTransNo() but when i run the code i get this error
Variable 'GetTransNo' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime"
please any one can help me for this

```
 Function GetTransNo() As String
        Try
            Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
            cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand("Select * From TblCart Where TransNo Like '" & sdate & "%' Order By Id Desc", cn)
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()
            If dr.HasRows Then

                GetTransNo = CLng(dr.Item("Transno").ToString) + 1
            Else
                GetTransNo = sdate & "0001"


            End If
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            cn.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try

        Return GetTransNo
    End Function
```

here where i call the function

```
Private Sub BtnNewOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNewOrder.Click
        If CheckTransaction() = True Then


            LblTransNo.Text = GetTransNo()
            With FrmSelectTable
                .LoadTable()

                .ShowDialog()
            End With
            loadcart()
        Else
            MsgBox("Transaction is already closed", vbExclamation)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you send the code where you call your function ?

Comment: @UserNam3
 I edit the code i write where i call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your function have a way where "GetTransNo" don't get any value : when it leave the try catch immediatly.
There is 2 solutions :

**Define a default value for GetTransNo :**

```
 Function GetTransNo() As String
    GetTransNo = ""
    Try
       [...]
    End Try

    Return GetTransNo
End Function
```

**Define a value in the catch, when the database reading fail :**

```
Function GetTransNo() As String
 
    Try
        [...]

    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        GetTransNo = ""
    End Try

    Return GetTransNo
End Function
```

And when you call the function, you can check if it retuns "" (= error occured), but in your case, it's not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, a value was returned from a function by writing `functionName = theReturnValue`, as the code in the question shows with `GetTransNo = sdate & "0001"`.

The modern way of returning a value is to use the [`Return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement) statement, as shown in this code:

```
Function GetTransNo() As String
    Dim sql = "SELECT TOP (1) TransNo FROM TblCart
               WHERE TransNo LIKE @TransNo
               ORDER BY Id DESC"

    Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim transNo As String = ""

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("yourConnectionStingGoesHere"),
            sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@TransNo",
                                                     .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                                                     .Value = sdate & "%"})

        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim rslt = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()

            If rslt Is Nothing Then
                transNo = sdate & "0001"
            Else
                transNo = (CLng(rslt) + 1).ToString()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)

        End Try

    End Using

    Return transNo

End Function
```

The compiler is being confused by `Return` with the name of the function.

Also, I used a parameter to pass the value - you should always use parameters as it is a good habit and prevents a lot of potential problems.

You must not try re-using a database connection (`cn` in the code in the question) more than once, as that too can lead to confusion. The database is made to be efficient creating a new connection every time.