# Printing receipt with report viewer problem

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to use report viewer to print receipt with pos system but i get always the first order printing details not the current order details
i think the problem with PrintPreview code section where i can put the code exactly

```
   Sub Savepayment()
        Try
            Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Dim stime As String = Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
            cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand("Insert into TblSales(transno,total,sdate,stime,cashier,discount,totalbill) values (@transno,@total,@sdate,@stime,@cashier,@discount,@totalbill) ", cn)
            With cm
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@transno", FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", CDbl(TxtBill.Text))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sdate)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stime", stime)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier", str_user)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", CDbl(TxtDiscount.Text))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalbill", CDbl(TxtTotal.Text))
                '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cash", CDbl(TxtCash.Text))
                '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", CDbl(TxtChange.Text))

                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            cn.Close()

            cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand("Update tblcart set status='Completed' Where transno like '" & FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text & "'", cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

            MsgBox("Payment successfully Saved!", vbInformation)

            With FrmReceipt
                .PrintPreview("Select c.id, p.Description, c.price, c.qty, c.total From tblcart as c inner join tblproduct as p on c.pid=p.id where c.status like 'Completed' and TransNo like '" & FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text & "'")

                .ShowDialog()
            End With


            With FrmPos
                .LblTransNo.Text = .GetTransNo()
                .loadcart()
            End With


            Me.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception

            cn.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: If this is part of the same system from your earlier question [Variable 'GetTransNo' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69595422/1115360), then I notice that `sdate` had the format `yyyyMMdd` there but it's got dashes `yyyy-MM-dd` here.

Comment: run the queryselect query in workbench and see which results you get an dwhat you expect

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes its the same system but the first sdate yyyyMMdd  this for the GetTransNo() function for the transaction format and the second variable Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to save payment i dont think that cause the problem

Comment: @Chaker 1) Ah, you can see that there are reasons for giving variables meaningful names if more than one person is going to see the code. 2) Monetary values need to use the Decimal type to avoid the rounding problems that can be encountered with floating point types like Double. 3) The SQL should use `=` when you mean equal to, not `LIKE`. 4) You should check the value of `FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text` at the point the query happens, in case there is some synchronisation problem that means it is not what you expected.

Comment: So, you've said you believe the issues is in the PrintPreview code section but you've not shown that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get the solution i add this code of refresh report on the load form event of the report form

```
 ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection should always be declared in the method where is it used with a `Using...End Using` block. Connection and commands need to be disposed (have their `Dispose` method called) to release unmanaged resources. `Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error. It also closes the connection.

Don't `Open` the connection until directly before the `Execute...` .

Don't use `AddWithValue` with Sql Server. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

You need to disconnect your database code from your user interface code. Show message boxes and interact with controls in the UI code.

I guessed that `TransNo` is a numeric type, a primary key and a foreign key. If it is an identity field, you should not be sending a value for it. Remove it from the field list, parameter list and the Add method for the Insert command.

Dates should be saved as dates. You will have problems later sorting and searching if they are not dates. I did not change this is the code.

```
Private cnStr As String = "Your connection String"

Sub Savepayment(TransNo As Integer, TotalBill As Decimal, str_user As String, Discount As Decimal, Total As Decimal)
    Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim stime As String = Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(cnStr)
        Using cm As New SqlCommand("Insert into TblSales(transno,total,sdate,stime,cashier,discount,totalbill) values (@transno,@total,@sdate,@stime,@cashier,@discount,@totalbill);", cn)
            With cm.Parameters
                .Add("@transno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TransNo
                .Add("@total", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TotalBill
                .Add("@sdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sdate
                .Add("@stime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stime
                .Add("@cashier", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str_user
                .Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Discount
                .Add("@totalbill", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Total
            End With
            cn.Open()
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        Using cm As New SqlCommand("Update tblcart set status='Completed' Where transno = @TransNo", cn)
            cm.Parameters.Add("@TransNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TransNo
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim TransNo = CInt(FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text)
    Dim User As String = "I don't know where this comes from"
    Dim BillTotal As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TxtBill.Text, BillTotal) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Total Bill.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Discount As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TxtDiscount.Text, Discount) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Discount")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim TotalAfterDiscount As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TxtTotal.Text, TotalAfterDiscount) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Total")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Try
        Savepayment(TransNo, BillTotal, User, Discount, TotalAfterDiscount)
        MsgBox("Payment successfully Saved!", vbInformation)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'I have no idea what this code is doing.
    With FrmReceipt
        .PrintPreview("Select c.id, p.Description, c.price, c.qty, c.total From tblcart as c inner join tblproduct as p on c.pid=p.id where c.status like 'Completed' and TransNo like '" & FrmPos.LblTransNo.Text & "'")
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
    With FrmPos
        .LblTransNo.Text = .GetTransNo()
        .loadcart()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get this exception error "arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"

Comment: Transno database field is Nvarchar not integer